# I broke something and I'm not sure what

Tags: customization, settings

I think I messed up my controls. Rather than zooming, my scroll wheel now scrolls through frames. And my middle mouse button seems to be snapping my view.

Comment: You 'Alt' key might be pressed un intentionally. In the preferences, using ALT key when moving the Mouse Wheel should Jog between frames.

Comment: Restart your computer as well. you might not have changed and keybinds in blender, but windows might have registered the key as constantly pressed. restarting will ensure this is not the case